# Java equivalent of openssl_encrypt and openssl_decrypt using AES 256 CBC encryption with provided secret key and IV

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am using third party application which is in PHP and mine is in java, for which I need to send a few data in an encrypted format. They have shared the secret key and IV. But I am not able to get the same output as they are getting while encryption. Although whatever I am encrypting in java, I am able to get the same while decrypting in java. Please help me out with this.

public static String secret_key = "abc";
public static String secret_iv = "abc@243";

```
public static String strKeyString = toHexString(getSHA(secret_key));
public static String ivString = toHexString(getSHA(secret_iv));
public static String strKey= strKeyString.substring(0, 16);
public static String strIv = ivString.substring(0, 16);

public static byte[] getSHA(String input)
{  
    // Static getInstance method is called with hashing SHA  
    MessageDigest md;
    try {
        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
         // digest() method called  
        // to calculate message digest of an input  
        // and return array of byte 
        return md.digest(input.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); 
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }  
    return null; 
} 
public static String toHexString(byte[] hash) 
{ 
    // Convert byte array into signum representation  
    BigInteger number = new BigInteger(1, hash);  

    // Convert message digest into hex value  
    StringBuilder hexString = new StringBuilder(number.toString(16));  

    // Pad with leading zeros 
    while (hexString.length() < 32)  
    {  
        hexString.insert(0, '0');  
    }  

    return hexString.toString();  
} 
public static String openssl_encrypt(String data) throws Exception {
    Cipher ciper = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(strKey.getBytes(), "AES");
    IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(strIv.getBytes(), 0, ciper.getBlockSize());

    // Encrypt
    ciper.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
    byte[] encryptedCiperBytes = ciper.doFinal(data.getBytes());
    
    System.out.println("Ciper encrypted : " + Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedCiperBytes));
    //Decrypt
    
    ciper.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,  key, iv);
    byte[] output = ciper.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedCiperBytes)));

    System.out.println("Ciper decrypted : " +new String(output).trim());
    
    return Base64.encodeBase64String(encryptedCiperBytes);
    
}
```

Comment: Check if the key and IV are the same as in PHP. Try to encrypt a longer text. Check if the ciphertext is the same at the beginning and has a different end. This would imply you are using a different padding.

Comment: Hi Marek. Thank you for your reply. I checked the key and IV are same in java and PHP. The ciphertext is not the same at the beginning itself, both are different.

Comment: Kindly share the PHP code as well and provide an complete test dataset  (plaintext, key, iv, ciphertext) to check any implementation.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you for your reply.
Please find the PHP code.
$output = false;
  $encrypt_method = "AES-256-CBC";
  $secret_key = 'abc';
  $secret_iv = 'abc@243';
  $key = hash('sha256', $secret_key);
  $iv = substr(hash('sha256', $secret_iv), 0, 16);
  if( $action == 'encrypt' ) {
   $output = openssl_encrypt($string, $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
   $output = base64_encode($output);
  }
  else if( $action == 'decrypt' ){
   $output = openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($string), $encrypt_method, $key, 0, $iv);
  }
  return $output;